# Show inequality $k\cot(x)<\cot\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)$

Tags: analysis, inequality

What is the best way to show the following inequality:

$$k\cot(x)<\cot\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)$$

for $k>1$ and $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$. By the way for $k<1$ the inequality reverses.

I can see it graphically. Moreover, the Taylor expansion around zero also can be used, but this only explains if we are near the zero. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

My second question, if a function behaves like a linear function, then the Taylor expansion near zero or at the infinity or around any point are really different things?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The cotangent function is far from being "almost linear". To such a point that it has no Taylor development at $0$ !!!

Answer (score 3):

Examine instead,

$$\tan x-k\tan\frac xk=\int_0^x (\sec^2 t-\sec^2 \frac tk )dt>0$$

becauee the integrand is positive for $k>1$. Therefore,

$$\tan x>k\tan\frac xk$$

Note that for $0<x<\frac\pi2$, $\tan x > \tan \frac xk > 0$. So, rearrange to get,

$$k\cot x<\cot\frac{x}{k}$$

Comment: Dear Quanto, I am really impressed the way how you approach the question, which is completely something I haven't imagined. Thank you so much for the explanation.

Comment: @user101496 - glad you liked it; you're welcome.